# Whitespace Issue - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, whitespace, removing-whitespace

[Whitespace Issue (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrvCl.png)

Hi everyone! I've got this issue for a long time now, tried many things, and still can't solve it. So, this is a **React-Router** project and the issue is this **whitespace** I don't understand.

1. I've searched in dev tools (Chrome) and there's nothing that overflows the normal width
2. This only happens on the **first page**, until the "You above all" section
3. I've removed all components until the "You above all" and still it appears

Here're the links:

Website: https://andre-rd-rodrigues.github.io/wheretofindme

Repository: https://github.com/andre-rd-rodrigues/wheretofindme/tree/main/src

I would much appreciate your help. Thank you and stay safe :)

Comment: share the code snippet of the relevant area. It's hard to figure out without looking ar code. use codesandbox.io if required.

Comment: I was just now adding the links ahaha thank you :)

Comment: :D ... ohh fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it ,its  in your services component and you component ,  I solved like this

```
.services-row {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#you-div {
    margin: 100px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: nice project btw

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much for the help and positive feedback :D Would you mind to explain what was going on? That way I could avoid future mess :)

Comment: yeah sure , so basically you were using aos animation library and in your services components and your you component ,  you're sliding elements of screen to the screen , and because you didn't set ``` overflow: hidden; ``` on their parents they affect their parents width

Comment: Yes! Makes perfect sense. I'll pay more attention next time now. Thank you so much once again ;)